# Access VBA: Form timer not showing MsgBox at the intended time

Tags: ms-access, timer, vba, ms-access-2013

I am trying to get the DB to close after 2 minutes have passed by (for testing purposes I am just making a `MsgBox` appear after the 2 minutes). To do this, I have a main form called `DTForm` and a hidden form called `Timer`. Both forms open on opening the DB but `Timer` opens in hidden mode.

**AutoExec Macro:**

```
1. Open DTForm (the main form)
2. Open Timer (the hidden form)
```

**Module 1:**

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public timer_start As Date
Public timer_end As Date
Public timer_diff As Integer
```

**DTForm (users will only see this form)**

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub Form_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)

    timer_start = Time

    timer_end = DateAdd("n", 2, timer_start)

End Sub
```

**Timer (the hidden form):**

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    timer_start = Time
    timer_end = DateAdd("n", 2, Time)

End Sub

Public Sub Form_Load()

    timer_start = Time
    timer_end = DateAdd("n", 2, Time)

End Sub

Public Sub Form_Timer()

    timer_diff = DateDiff("n", timer_end, Time)

    If timer_diff >= 0 Then

        'Application.Quit
        MsgBox "timer reached 0"
        timer_start = Time
        timer_end = DateAdd("n", 2, Time)

    End If

End Sub
```

**Update - the problem:** So now the problem is the mouse. It looks like just moving the mouse around the form does nothing. *However*, moving the mouse from the navigation pane to the form and back (in and out) *does* trigger the mouse movement. This seems really counter-intuitive - why not just consider all mouse movements?

**Notes:** Added `Option Explicit` to the tops of both forms and fixed some missing variable declarations.

Comment: application.OnTime might work better for you? Or couldn't you set the DB connection to time out after 2 minutes of no use?

Comment: What is your Form's Timer property? What is timer_start? You don't have it defined anywhere. Add Option Explicit at top - then declare all variables you're using. If you're going to track a variables value across events you need to declare it at the top - above all subs

Comment: @CodyG. I need the whole DB to close though.

Comment: First, your users will hate you for this "feature". I wouldn't use this application. What if they get a phone call while editing a record?

Comment: Second, you haven't solved the issue. The variables like `timer_start` are members of the `Timer` form, you need to address them accordingly. **Use `Option Explicit`**.

Comment: Third, once you have solved that issue, it's still not going to work, unless `DTForm` is the **only** form in your application. Once another form is opened on top of it, it will no longer receive mouse moves.

Comment: @Andre My users will not hate me because this is a necessity. Is there any way I can make this work with multiple forms?

Comment: With regards to the mouse movement I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go through with it, the `Form_MouseMove` event must be in **every form**, because only the active form receives the MouseMove event.

Note: you actually don't need the `timer_start` variable at all. You can remove it and keep only:

```
Public Sub Form_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)

    timer_end = DateAdd("n", 2, Time)

End Sub
```

Or somewhat cleaner:

```
Public Sub Form_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)

    Call UpdateTimer()

End Sub
```

and in your Module1:

```
Public Sub UpdateTimer()

    timer_end = DateAdd("n", 2, Time)

End Sub
```

in case you decide to change the time interval...

Note:
`timer_diff` should be a local variable in `Timer.Form_Timer()`, since it's only used there.

Comment: Am I even using the correct event when using `Form_MouseMove`?? I edited the question to explain. Basically, moving the mouse over the form doesn't trigger the event. I thought it would...

Comment: @whatwhatwhat: Oh, interesting. That event is triggered only rarely when I test it. You have to create a **rectangle** in the background of the form (it must not be transparent), and use its `.MouseMove` event instead of the Form's.

Comment: Oh that worked! The rectangle in the background was a great idea! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a variable scope issue to me.  By default your variables are local.

Unless timer_end is declared as a global or public variable, it is out of scope as soon as you leave the sub where it is defined.  So the timer_end in Form_timer is a totally different variable than the one in your MouseMove event (even though they have the same name).

This is one reason why many people put "option explicit" at the beginning of their code as it forces you to declare your variables.

You could also pursue a design strategy where you pass the variable as a parameter instead of making it global or public

Comment: Fixed the issue with variable scope but now there's a new problem: the DB closes after 2 minutes no matter what. See edited question.

Comment: The mousemove will only fire if the mouse movement is within the borders of the form.  As soon as the focus changes to some other form or application, you will no longer fire the mousemove event.

Comment: Something is still strange though - here's how I tested it. I know the MsgBox will appear (I commented out the Application.Quit and switched to the MsgBox) after 2 minutes right? So the countdown starts. Then, after **1 minute** I went back to the form (from another application) and clicked some controls, typed some things, and generally moved the mouse verywhere. That should have reset the timer right? Nope, it still gave the MsgBox right on the 2 minute cue. So the timer is not resetting upon mouse movement.

Comment: Couldn't I just make the `timer_` variables global?

Comment: Please. Add `Option Explicit` to all modules. Then do `Debug -> Compile`. It will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @Andre ok I did that and fixed some areas where I didn't declare my variables. But still nothing happens after 2 minutes (see updated question)

Comment: @whatwhatwhat: Ok... you fixed it, but in a wrong way. Now you have the variables in each form module separately, they don't know of each other. It would be best to put the `Public` variable declarations into a standard module (insert one if you don't have one yet). Then both forms can access the variables. Remove the variable declarations from both form modules. -- Worth reading: [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: @Andre edited. Any tips on the mouse movement problem?

Answer (score 1):

`DateDiff("s", timer_end, Time)` will return a negative value until the 10 seconds of inactivity, then the condition must be changed to `>=` and the time interval to 1000 (1 second)  1 millisecond is too fast.

Also to make sure the  variables are ok add `option explicit` clause

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Dim timer_start as Variant
Dim timer_end   as Variant

Public Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer) 
    timer_start = Time
End Sub

Public Sub Form_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    timer_start = Time
    timer_end = DateAdd("s", 10, timer_start)

    Me.Label6.Caption = timer_start
    Me.Label8.Caption = timer_end
End Sub

Public Sub Form_Timer() 
    If DateDiff("s", timer_end, Time) >= 0 Then
        MsgBox "timer reached 0"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Fixed the variable scope, but now there is a new problem (see edited question).

Comment: @whatwhatwhat is the `Timer Interval` value equal to 1000*60*2?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat and Form_MouseMove must be added to every form in your DB... also check your timer interval in hidden form

Comment: Timer interval is set to 1000. I figured it should check every second to see if the time has elapsed.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat Use `Debug.print "Message"` to make sure if that are working ok